# Include Claims In IdentityServer4/AspnetIdentity JwtToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, .net-5

I created a new react web application using visual studio and the react application template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

When I created the app, I also chose the Individual user accounts authentication option:

[image]

I created an authorization policy like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
        {
            config.AddPolicy("ShouldBeAdmin",
                options => options.RequireClaim("Admin"));
        });
```

My user in the aspnet identity database had the claim associated with it:
[image]

When I log in with my user, the jwt token I get does not contain the Admin claim, so endpoints protected with my authorization rule do not work.  How do I get the claims into the jwt token?

Comment: You need to implement an `IProfileService`: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for this problem.  While this doesn't add the claims to the jwt token, I can look up the claims from the database each time a request comes in using the onTokenValidated event.  Something like this:

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
            IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
            options =>
            {
                var onTokenValidated = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    await onTokenValidated(context);
                    var userManger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                        .GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                    var user = await userManger.FindByIdAsync(context.Principal?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    var claims = await userManger.GetClaimsAsync(user);
                    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                    context.Principal?.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                };
            });
```

This solution is based on this Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-the-api-authentication-handler

And this blob post:
https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2

I'm still looking into implementing IProfileService based on abdusco's comment.